# how can transpose row to column in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, sapb1

I have the following structure of data

```
**ParentItem        ChildItem**        description
ParentItem1         childItem1       childitem1 desc
ParentItem1         childItem2       childItem2 desc
ParentItem1         childItem3       childitem3 desc
ParentItem1         childItem4       childitem4 desc
ParentItem2         childItem1       childitem1 desc 
ParentItem2         childItem2       childItem2 desc
```

transpose to

```
ParentItem1       childItem1,       childitem2,      childitem3,       childitem3
                  childitem1 desc   childitem2 desc   childitem3 desc  childitem4 desc

ParentItem2       childItem1,       childitem2,      
                  childitem1 desc   childitem2 desc
```

i tried this but giving me error message `The remaining text does not appear to be a part of the formula`

```
stringvar mydata;
if {ParentItem1} = previous(ParentItem1) then mydata := mydata + ', ' + {childItem1};
else  
mydata := mydata + ', ' + {childItem1};
mydata;
```

i also tried the following but that displayed multiple rows i want to display all in the same line Note: {WOR1.ItemCode} is the field which contains Childitems

```
if{WOR1.ItemCode} like "20*" then{WOR1.ItemCode}
else if{WOR1.ItemCode} like "40*" then{WOR1.ItemCode}
else if{WOR1.ItemCode} like "10*" then{WOR1.ItemCode}
else if{WOR1.ItemCode} like "50*" then{WOR1.ItemCode}
else if{WOR1.ItemCode} like "320*" then{WOR1.ItemCode}
else if{WOR1.ItemCode} like "30*" then{WOR1.ItemCode}
else ""
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked into inserting a Crosstab into your report?

Comment: @R.McMillan i added what I have tried

Comment: Is there a predictable or finite number of child items for each parent item?

Comment: @R.McMillan Thank you for getting back to me, Not more than 10

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something similar to this using multiple columns (and it's much easier to maintain).

First group by `**ParentItem`, then format the 'Details' section to use multiple columns, in the 'Layout' tab set the width and select 'Across then down'.

You can even set the group header to 'Underlay following sections' to move it inline with the first detail item.